# jsonwebtoken.sign() fails with expiresIn option set

Tags: javascript, json-web-token

I need to get a token by signing a user ID with [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken):

```
var token = jwt.sign(accounts[request.headers.login].id, privateKey, {expiresIn: 60});
```

Where `id` and `privateKey` are strings.

The error is `Error: Uncaught error: "expiresIn" should be a number of seconds or string representing a timespan eg: "1d", "20h", 60`.
If I remove options object at all, it works, but without options I need to set.

The issue seems to be simple but I don't know how to fix it, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken#jwtsignpayload-secretorprivatekey-options-callback

payload could be an object literal, buffer or string. **Please note that exp is only set if the payload is an object literal.**

Comment: Oh, seems like I can't set expire date if payload is a string. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Set the **payload as an object** if you want to be able to set the `expiresIn` option

```
var token = jwt.sign(
    {id: accounts[request.headers.login].id}, // object and not string
    privateKey,
    {expiresIn: '60d'} // added days, default for ex 60 would be ms, you can also provide '1h' etc
)
```

Comment: "be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc), otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default" 
It would be 60ms not 60 seconds

Comment: @Seb edit my answer please! with example providing units ;)

Comment: I get the 'Suggested edit queue is full' error from stackoverflow

Comment: the PAYLOAD!!!! needs to be and object (gush what a crappy error message),

Comment: also: 60d should be '60d'

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same question.There is my answer.
**the initial code**

```js
const setToken = function (data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const token = jwt.sign( data , signkey, { expiresIn: "1d" });
    resolve(token);
  });
};
```

The first parameter(data) should be object or add braces({});
**the edited code**

```js
const setToken = function (data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const token = jwt.sign({ data }, signkey, { expiresIn: "1d" });
    resolve(token);
  });
};
```

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Use the formatting tools to put the code here,

Answer (score -1):

In my case, it was a wrong file name that was referencing the env variables.

```
technicianAuthSchema.methods.getSignedToken = async function() {
return jwt.sign( { id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRE, } );};
```

instead of this

```
technicianAuthSchema.methods.getSignedToken = async function() {
return jwt.sign( { id: this._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE, } );};
```

> Wrong file name: expiresIn: process.env.EXPIRE
> Correct file name: expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRE