# Error: expiresIn should be a number of seconds or string rep

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a token by signing in. Here's the code.

```
db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async (error, results) => {
      console.log(results);
      if( !results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password)) ) {
        res.status(401).render('login', {
          message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
        })
      } else {
        const id = results[0].id;

        const token = jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
          expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
        });

        console.log("The token is " + token);

        const cookieOptions = {
          expires: new Date(
            date.now() + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60
          ),
          httpOnly: true
        }

        res.cookie('jwt', token, cookeOptions);
        res.status(200).redirect("/")
      }
```

The error is `Error: expiresIn should be a number of seconds or string rep`

but I can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Please help

Comment: Did you add the JWT_EXPIRES_IN  && JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES in your .env file ?

Comment: Try to `console.log(process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN)` and see what you are passing in that prop, then compare it to what is expected in the docs

Comment: Maybe it will help... https://stackoverflow.com/a/35138357/13700761 Good Luck!

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth yes

Comment: @YuriMckoy Try to print in the console. The **expiresIn** parameter accepts only a  string .It should be like **expiresIn: '1h'**

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth no it just has my API keys in there

Comment: @MithiridiPrasanth why do I have to add a cookie ?